# How do I send data from Processing to an HTML page

Tags: three.js, processing

I'm looking for a way to send data from processing to a web browser, specifically, I'm looking for a way to send data to Three.js and display it visually, but I'm a little stumped at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main Processing ports in javascript: [ProcessingJS](http://processingjs.org/) and the more recent [p5.js](http://p5js.org/).

The p5.js port should be pretty easy to integrate: check out this [wiki article on js libraries](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Integrating-other-libraries)

It depends on experience and personal preference: you should totally be able to integrate using either of them.

**p5.js** is plain vanilla javascript so no problem integrating, but you need to be mindful about Processing syntax and the p5.js equivalent.

**Processing.js** should allow you to keep most of your Processing (java looking) syntax as is, but you'll need to get a reference to the Processing.js sketch from JS to integrate with three.js. Be sure to check [Pomax's Guide to Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/articles/PomaxGuide.html) for more in depth notes and if you're using the JavaScript mode in the Processing IDE also see the Environment and HTML5 examples.

**Update**
There's a chance you're simply looking for a way to send data/variables from an existing Processing sketch to the browser, in which case websockets is the way to go. You Processing sketch will also need to become a websocket server (which it can do via a java library), then your three.js webpage would become a websocket client. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900187/processing-how-to-send-data-through-websockets-to-javascript-application) for more details.

Comment: Yeah, I have processing sending data to an Arduino which is triggering LEDs ... I was looking for a a way to simulate the LEDS before I buy 400 of them and Three.js looks promising ... so it would be ideal if I could send the data in the same way I'm sending to the arduino

Comment: Sounds like a fun project. Please do share more when you make some progress. You should be able to roll a nice visualisation with three.js. You could probably go for a full simulation with a 3d editor and a bit of scripting. The scripting would automate the animation process and the 3d editor would give you access to a nice ray tracer. On the pragmatic side, the amount of time/effort might be worth more than 400 LEDs :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use Processing to visualize the LEDs? If you are using Processing already for the lighting logic, just visualize it there, no need for a browser or Three.js.