# java websocket client does not connect

Tags: java, websocket, java-websocket

I'm trying to connect to an ethernet module via websocket protocol. I've successfully connected to module using javascript and nodejs. But I want to create a standalone application using java.

I use the following library https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket and conected to a nodejs socket server succesfully. But The same code fails to connect to said ethernet module, which successfully connected via javascript and node js.

I've tried both of these sample codes.

- https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/wiki#user-content-client-example
- [Processing - how to send data (through websockets?) to javascript application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900187/#answers-header)

log for successful connection:

```
write(153): {GET / HTTP/1.1
host: localhost:9991
upgrade: websocket
connection: Upgrade
sec-websocket-version: 13
sec-websocket-key: tJQdsjTjLaoNzW5lzPh3pA==

}
process(129): {HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: 4s+UFW9gNz7iCNRLE0aK5ohjl00=

}
open using draft: Draft_17
```

log for failed connection:

```
write(157): {GET / HTTP/1.1
host: 192.168.1.10:6432
upgrade: websocket
connection: Upgrade
sec-websocket-version: 13
sec-websocket-key: ZQMlepwV8lqyuSglz/Qx2Q==

}
```

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: finally, I've ended up using NodeJS.